# Div margin problems

Tags: html, css

I have a div element of `width:90%;` and `margin: 80px auto;`. The html has a fixed background image. When I added a link to bootstrap, the left and right margins of the div filled in with white. How to solve this problem?

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="logo">
        <header>
            <h5>royal apartments for you</h5>
                <ul id="menu">
                  <li><a href="index.html">Main</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Apartments</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
                </ul>
        </header>
    </div>
    <div class="slider">

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html { 
  background: url(images/146987895643799.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.header-container{
    width: 92%;
    margin: 80px auto 0 auto;
}

.logo{
    background-color: #9fcb00;
    height: 350px;
}
```

I added this to the HTML: 
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">`

Comment: It's kinda hard to give you any advice without a bit more info. What link to bootstrap? What's the basic container hierarchy? What's supposed to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Element Inspector in your browser's developer tools. Look at the elements where you are getting unwanted styles (i.e. the white background). Figure out where they come from. Then delete them or override them.

Bootstrap sets the background colour of the body to white. That covers up the background on the HTML element. Write a different style for the body to change that.